# When is composition in $A$-mod surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be any field.  Suppose that $A$ is a finite dimensional associative $k$-algebra.  Let $A$-mod be the category of finite dimensional (over $k$) left $A$-modules.  Then composition of homomorphisms induces a linear map:
$$
Hom_A(X,A)\otimes_k Hom_A(A,Y) \longrightarrow Hom_A(X,Y).
$$
If $A=k$, then this map is an isomorphism.  For arbitrary $A$, is this map surjective for all $X,Y\in A$-mod?

If not, then for which algebras $A$ will this map be surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property does not hold in general.  In fact, it holds if and only if $A$ is semisimple.

Using your notation, the image of the composition map is the set of morphisms $f:X\to Y$ that factor through a free module.  Indeed, the image of a sum $\sum_{i=1}^n g_i\otimes h_i$ is exactly the composition of the morphism
$$ \pmatrix{g_1 \\ \vdots \\ g_n}: X\to A^n $$
with the morphism
$$ \pmatrix{h_1 \ldots h_n}:A^n\to Y.$$

Thus the composition map is surjective if and only if every morphism between any two modules $X$ and $Y$ factors through a free module.

If $A$ is semisimple, then any module $X$ is a direct factor of a free module, so any morphism from $X$ to $Y$ factors through a free module.  Hence the composition map is surjective.

Now, if the composition map is surjective, then the identity morphism $X\to X$ factors through a free module.  This means that $X$ is a direct factor of a free module.  Since this is true for any module $X$, we get that all $A$-modules are projective, and this implies that $A$ is semisimple.

Comment: It is a nice answer, Thank you!  I have a follow-up question:  Is it also true that the category of all $k$-linear functors from $A$-mod to finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces is equivalent to $A$-mod, iff $A$ is semisimple?

Comment: @Jordy Thanks! The answer to your follow-up question is yes.  If $A$ is semisimple, and if $S_1, \ldots, S_r$ are the simple $A$-modules up to isom., then the functor from the category $Fun(A-mod, k-Vect)$ to $A-mod$ sending a functor $F$ to the $A$-module $\bigoplus_r S_r\otimes_k F(S_r)$ is an equivalence.  Now, the functor sending an indecomposable $M$ to $k$ and other indecomposables to $0$ is a simple functor.  If $A$ is semisimple, then there are more indecomposables than there are simples in $A-mod$, so the category of functors has more simples than $A-mod$ has.